# dynamically added <ul> not firing click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have created `<ul>` containing two `<li>` , but none of them firing `click` event .

**`code`**

```
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.className = "dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap pagination";
    var UL = document.createElement('ul');
    var L1 = document.createElement('li');
    L1.className = 'prev';
    var A1 = document.createElement('a');
    A1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('← Previous'));
    A1.id = 'B1';
    L1.appendChild(A1);
    UL.appendChild(L1);
    var L3 = document.createElement('li');
    L3.className = 'active';
    var A3 = document.createElement('a');
    A3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('1'));
    L3.appendChild(A3);
    UL.appendChild(L3);
    d.appendChild(UL);
    var L2 = document.createElement('li');
    L2.className = 'next';
    var A2 = document.createElement('a');
    A2.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Next →'));
    L2.appendChild(A2);
    A2.id = 'B2';
    UL.appendChild(L2);
   var root = document.getElementById('rose');
   root.appendChild(d);
```

**`script`**

```
$('#B1').click(function () {

        alert('back');
    });

    $('#B2').click(function () {

        alert('next');
    });
```

Comment: check this out > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954932/difference-between-jquery-click-bind-live-delegate-trigger-and-on

Comment: check this it worked for me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073425/create-element-with-eventlistener-dynamically-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for event delegation

```
$('#myContainer').on("click", element , function(){
   alert('back');
});
```

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi Ordinary event handlers are only added to elements that exist at the time. Using `.on('click',selector)` will check if the clicked element matches the selector, even if it was added later.

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi SO question: [Direct vs delegated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on)

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi Just do it in the body of the function, where it currently has `alert('back');`

Comment: i have tried this :   $(this).attr("disabled", true); but no difference ... @Scimonster

Comment: Try `$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");`?

Answer (score 0):

```
use jQuery 'on' method to fire click function on dynamically added ul.

example :-    $('#parent').on("click", "#child", function() {});
```

**Answer**

```
$('#parentDiv').on('click','#B1', function () {

    alert('back');
});

$('#parentDiv').on('click','#B2', function ()  {

    alert('next');
});
```